# Javascript: Button onclick showing next div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a thing with JavaScript that where I click on a button it shows the next div and the one after that and more. So it's a 'next' button. It would also be nice to have a 'previous' button.

I've tried everything, but can't seem to find the solution. I'd really appreciate some advice or help, thank you!

Any help please?

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="featured">
      <input id="button-next" type="button" value="next"/>
      <img src="photos/bookcover/Alluredbyyou.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
      <p>ALLURED BY YOU</p>
      <span>Lorem text part 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="featured2">
      <input id="button-next" type="button" value="next"/>
      <img src="photos/bookcover/Notyourmarrysue.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
      <p>Rebecca Frost</p>
      <span>Lorem text part 2</span>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <script>
$(document).on('click','#button-next', function() {
     $('.featured').removeClass('featured2').next('.featured').addClass('active');
});

</script>
```

```
.featured, .featured2 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 16%;
  margin-top: 4%;
  width: 980px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: #CFD0CD;

}
.featured img, .featured2 img {
  width: 230px;
  height: 360px;
  margin-top:4%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  float: left;

}
.featured p, .featured2 p{
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  margin-right: 51%;
  width: 18%;
  
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family:'poppins';
  text-align: left;

}
.featured span, .featured2 span {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 0%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  width: 65%;

  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

    height: 75%;
  text-align: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break:normal;
  line-height: 30px;
  white-space: inherit;

}
#button-next{
    color: #000000;
    float: right;
    font-size: 19px;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
    padding: 5px 50px;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.0);
    transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;

  }
  #button-next:hover {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
  }
```

Comment: Ids must be unique within a page. You can't have two "button-next" elements. I would move the buttons outside of the wrapper, and one handler for an element with a "previous" class, and another with a "next" class.

Comment: @Andy Hi, could you edit my code, so I could have a better understanding of what you meant? I can move the button-next button outside the wrapper but how do I make it display inside the .featured div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution in Vanilla JavaScript

```js
const scrollButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-btn')
const slideItems = Array.apply(
    null,
  document.querySelectorAll('.slide-item')
)

const getActiveIndex = () => slideItems.findIndex(item => {
    return item.classList.contains('active')
})

scrollButtons.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
    const activeIndex = getActiveIndex()
    slideItems[activeIndex].classList.remove('active')

    let newActiveIndex
    if (target.id === 'previous') {
      newActiveIndex = activeIndex === 0 ? slideItems.length - 1 : activeIndex - 1
    } else {
      newActiveIndex = activeIndex === slideItems.length - 1 ? 0 : activeIndex + 1
    }

    slideItems[newActiveIndex].classList.add('active')
  })
})
```

```css
.featured, .featured2 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 16%;
  margin-top: 4%;
  width: 980px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: #CFD0CD;

}
.featured img, .featured2 img {
  width: 230px;
  height: 360px;
  margin-top:4%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  float: left;

}
.featured p, .featured2 p{
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  margin-right: 51%;
  width: 18%;
  
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family:'poppins';
  text-align: left;

}
.featured span, .featured2 span {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 0%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  width: 65%;

  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

    height: 75%;
  text-align: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break:normal;
  line-height: 30px;
  white-space: inherit;

}

#wrapper div:not(.active) {
  display: none;
}

.slide-btn {
    color: #000000;
    float: right;
    font-size: 19px;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
    padding: 5px 50px;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.0);
    transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;

  }
  .slide-btn:hover {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <input class="slide-btn" id="previous" type="button" value="previous"/>
    <input class="slide-btn" id="next" type="button" value="next"/>
    <div class="featured slide-item active">
      <img src="photos/bookcover/Alluredbyyou.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
      <p>ALLURED BY YOU</p>
      <span>Lorem text part 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="featured2 slide-item">
      <img src="photos/bookcover/Notyourmarrysue.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
      <p>Rebecca Frost</p>
      <span>Lorem text part 2</span>
    </div>  
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for, clean and simple, thank you! :)

Comment: Sorry, quick question, Is there any way I could have buttons stand in the div at the bottom right? Or bottom center?

Comment: Honestly, that's kinda difficult to do with your current code structure, so I decided to re-write the entire thing. Feel free to use it https://jsfiddle.net/9x58euy7. Btw, if you want to learn more about flexbox here is an awesome free interactive course https://scrimba.com/learn/flexbox

Comment: Thank you so much for re-writing the entire thing. It functions exactly as I wanted it to! Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain an id variable to so you can tell where in the slideshow you are.

So, add ids to your featured items in the form of [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), and then create a function that initialises an id variable to `1`, and then returns a new function that adds as the actual listener.

Then based on the id you can show/hide the relevant featured sections, and *also* disable/enable the buttons (which are now in their own separate section) at the same time.

```js
// Call `handleClick` which sets ups the initial id
// and then returns a new function that which will
// called whenever a button is clicked on
$(document).on('click', 'button', handleClick());

function handleClick() {

  // Initialise the id
  let id = 1;

  // Get the number of featured items from the DOM
  // We'll be using this number to compare against the id
  const items = $('.featured').length;

  // Utility function to toggle a show class for
  // featured item who has a matching data id
  function toggleFeatured(id) {
    $(`.featured[data-id=${id}]`).toggle('show');
  }

  // Disables/enables the buttons depending
  // on the id
  function updateButtons(id) {
    $('button').prop('disabled', false);
    if (id === 1) {
      $('.previous').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    if (id === items) {
      $('.next').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  }

  // This is the function that is returned
  // to the listener
  return function() {

    // It grabs the button class (previous/next)
    const cl = $(this).attr('class');

    // And depending on which it is first use
    // the utility function to toggle (remove) the
    // `show` class from the current featured item...
    toggleFeatured(id);

    // ...increase the id...
    if (cl === 'previous' && id > 1) --id;
    if (cl === 'next' && id < items) ++id;

    // ...then toggle the `show` on the item that
    // matches the new id, and update the buttons
    toggleFeatured(id);
    updateButtons(id);

  }

}
```

```css
.featured { display: none; }
.show { display: block; }
.buttons { margin-bottom: 1em; }
button:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="buttons">
  <button class="previous" type="button" disabled>Previous</button>
  <button class="next" type="button">Next</button>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div data-id="1" class="featured show">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/000/fff">
    <p>ALLURED BY YOU</p>
    <span>Lorem text part 1</span>
  </div>
  <div data-id="2" class="featured">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/cf5fcf/000000">
    <p>Rebecca Frost</p>
    <span>Lorem text part 2</span>
  </div>
  <div data-id="3" class="featured">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x100/cf815f/000000">
    <p>Bob Marley</p>
    <span>Lorem text part 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  You're a lifesaver! This was exactly what I was looking for. I also would like to ask whether it would be possible to change the transition animation? Because whenever I click next or previous, it pulls up the other divs below and then down again.

Comment: Probably. I don't use jQuery these days [but there is a lot of documentation](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/). @NobleF